# How To Save A Parse 'Server.js' Change/Configuration (Running on AWS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, parse-platform, bitnami

I set up my Parse server on Amazon AWS using the 'Parse Server Powered By Bitnami' image. I've been able to successfully connect to the server using the Java SSH Client from my browser. I was wondering how one would be able to save the htdocs -> server.js file after editing it. I've been trying to save the appName after changing it but every command that I have attempted to use hasn't worked. Sorry if this is a trivial question, I'm somewhat new to this particular process. I'd appreciate it if anybody could help me. Thanks!

Edit: I've tried using this command: `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart parse` but I receive an error regarding me not being privileged enough to use the command.

Comment: Bitnami developer here. The permissions of the server.js file allow the bitnami user to edit that files, could you please let us know which user you're using to edit that file? In case you can't edit it, could you please share the output of the following command? `ls -la /opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/server.js`. Regarding the issue restarting the server, could you please post here the exact error message you're getting? Thanks

Comment: Hello, sorry for the long wait, didn't see this comment until now. I managed to get it save/work properly after restarting the actual EC2 instance itself. Regardless, thanks for the help!

Comment: Hello! glad you could solve your issue. To help the community I would post an answer and I will mark it as the solution. You will make life easier if somebody comes here to look for an answer. Regards!